# Creating a meshgrid from [-1,1] to apply conformal maps to an image

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am using a piece of code that performs a conformal mapping operation on an image (it performs a log in the complex plane).

I am not sure if (and why) complex numbers are the reason why one needs a meshgrid that goes specifically from [-1,1]. If anyone has pointers or any reading material it will be appreciated.

**QUESTION 1:** These are the lines that I don't understand (**why it needs to go from -1 to 1?**)

```
image = np.array(cv2.imread(inFile)) #reading an image from file
row, col = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]  #taking dimensions of image
vec1 = np.linspace(-1, 1, num=row, endpoint=True) #creating a vector of equally spaced points
vec2 = np.linspace(-1, 1, num=col, endpoint=True)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(vec2, vec1) #using the previous vectors to create a matrix of points.
```

**QUESTION 2:** Also, this part I don't understand, my guess it's that it's reversing the [-1,1] story from before

```
  def create_X_new_and_Y_new(x, y, row, col):
        Xnew = (x / np.max(np.abs(x)) + 1) * col / 2
        Ynew = (y / np.max(np.abs(y)) + 1) * row / 2
        Xnew = np.clip(Xnew, 0, col - 1)
        Ynew = np.clip(Ynew, 0, row - 1)
        Xnew = np.floor(Xnew).astype(int)
        Ynew = np.floor(Ynew).astype(int)
        return Xnew, Ynew
```

**TO ADD MORE BACKGROUND INFO:**
The story goes like this:

1. On Question 1 above I read an image and use its coordinates to create a meshgrid. I obtain the `X, Y` coordinate vectors from this grid. On a later step, I pass these coordinates into a function that creates a complex plane off them and applies the Log on this complex plane:

   ```
   def log_deformation(x,y):
       Z = X + iY
       lnz = np.log(Z)
       return np.real(lnz), np.imag(lnz)
   ```
2. Then, the code calls the `create_X_new_and_Y_new(x, y, row, col)` (from Question 2 above) to create a new plane. I am not sure what is doing there, and why is needed.
3. Then, to save the new image I map the image's pixels to the newly created plane, and save the results as a new image using: `out = cv2.remap(image, x, y, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)`

**The whole code goes like this:**

1. Read image from file, take its dimensions
2. Create a Cartesian plane using a meshgrid from [-1,1] **(not sure why)**
3. Transform the Cartesian plane into the complex plane ->`log_deformation()`
4. Apply Log on the complex plane
5. Apply the odd transformation: `create_X_new_and_Y_new(x, y, row, col)`  **(not sure why)**
6. Map the image from the original plane to the transformed plane above ->`cv2.map()`
7. Save

Thank you very much!

Comment: still, meshgrid from [-1, 1] in image processing means you are transferring your image into image coordinates (from the integer typed pixel coordinates). Propably for remapping (what you are doing in function `create_X_new_and_Y_new()`).

Comment: It looks like the logarithmic mapping needs coordinates in the given range. `create_X_new_and_Y_new` converts coordinates from a range of [-1,1] to a range of [0,width-1], as needed by `remap`.

Comment: The logarithm mapping applied here maps circles to straight lines. Indeed you need to choose the coordinate system appropriately for that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#The_complex_logarithm_as_a_conformal_map

Comment: Thank you @CrisLuengo
And the part 2 is mapping back to the "normal" plane?

Comment: Yes, it’s mapping back to normal image pixel coordinates.

Comment: Copied my comments into an actual answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping of pixel coordinates to the [-1,1] coordinate system is not *because* the use of complex numbers, but because the complex logarithmic mapping used works best in this range. This mapping [maps circles to straight lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#The_complex_logarithm_as_a_conformal_map), the origin of the coordinate system used is the origin of the circles being mapped, so the [-1,1] coordinate system sets the origin of the mapping in the middle of the image.

The second mapping maps the output of the complex logarithmic mapping to normal pixel coordinates, such that `cv2.remap` can move the pixels to all the right places.

Comment: A thank you and a virtual hug. Thank you very much!!!!

When you say " so the [-1,1] coordinate system sets the origin of the mapping in the middle of the image." is there a place where I can read more about this? I am a newbie and it's hard for me to see this setting to the "middle of the image". Thank you.

Comment: @Toofreak: The origin of the coordinate system is where `X==0` and `Y==0`. This is right in the middle of the image, in the middle of the [-1,1] range for each dimension. I suggest you display those intermediate images, and examine what values end up where. Or do this for a small 9x9 input image, and just print the matrices to the screen. That always helps me a lot visualize what the math does.